# How can I assign initial data to some variables in literal object before use

Tags: javascript, object

I have an literal object which do something, this object must assigns some initial data to variables before use any of its methods.

```
var slideshow = {

    slideshowBox: null,
    slideImages: null,
    slideImagesLen: 0,

    init: function(){
        this.slideshowBox = document.getElementById('slideshow');
        this.slideImages = document.getElementById('images');
        this.slideImagesLen = this.slideImages.children.length;
    },
    show: function(){
        return this.slideImagesLen;
    }

};
```

But the problem when use any of its method you must firstly use `init` method then use I can use any of other methods, but this behavior is not good.

```
slideshow.init()
console.log(slideshow.show());
```

Also I have tried to use the following way:

```
(function(){   
    var slideshow = {

        slideshowBox: null,
        slideImages: null,
        slideImagesLen: 0,

        init: function(){
            this.slideshowBox = document.getElementById('slideshow');
            this.slideImages = document.getElementById('images');
            this.slideImagesLen = this.slideImages.children.length;
        },
        show: function(){
            return this.slideImagesLen;
        }
    };
    slideshow.init();
})();
```

But, there are  some errors like `this.slideImages is null`, `slideshow.show is not a function`

I want any way to call `init` method automatically before use any method and without need to calls it manually.

Answer (score 0):

you should try to use prototypal inheritance with a constructor here.

```
(function(){
  var Slideshow = function () {
    this.slideshowBox = document.getElementById('slideshow');
    this.slideImages = document.getElementById('images');
    this.slideImagesLen = this.slideImages.children.length;
  };

  Slideshow.prototype.show = function () {
    return this.slideImagesLen;
  };

  var slideShowInstance = new Slideshow();
  slideShowInstance.show();

})();
```

I actually would go a bit further to make it more extendable

```
  var Slideshow = function (slideShowId, images) {
    this.slideshowBox = slideShowId;
    this.slideImages = images;
    this.slideImagesLen = this.slideImages.children.length;
  };


  var slideShowId = document.getElementById('slideshow'),
      images = document.getElementById('images');

  var slideShowInstance = new Slideshow(slideShowId, images);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try returning `Object` `_slideshow` , after calling `_slideshow.init` within function `slides`

```js
var slides = function(options) {
  return (function(opts) {
  var _slideshow = opts || {

    slideshowBox: null,
    slideImages: null,
    slideImagesLen: 0,

    init: function() {
      this.slideshowBox = document.getElementById('slideshow');
      this.slideImages = document.getElementById('images');
      this.slideImagesLen = this.slideImages.children.length;
    },
    show: function() {
      return this.slideImagesLen;
    }

  };
  _slideshow.init();
  return Object.create(_slideshow)
}(options))
};

var slideshow = slides();

console.log("slideImagesLen:", slideshow.show(), "slideshow:", slideshow);
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
  <div id="images">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/nature" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but your answer a bit complicated in addition to as nested and not easy to understand it.

Comment: @LionKing Which portion having difficulty understanding ?

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but your code idea not clear for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways. For example:

```
var slideshow = {
        ...
    init: function () {
            ...
        return this;
    }
        ...
}.init();
```

Or if that's still too manual, you can simply use an IIFE within the object literal:

```
var slideshow = {
        ...
    init: (function init () {
            ...
        return init;
    }())
        ...
}
```

In both cases the referred HTML elements must exist before creating the object.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately the two ways do not work fine and appear two errors, `this.slideImages is null` and `slideshow is undefined`.

Comment: @LionKing They do not, if the HTML elements exist. If it's possible that they don't exist at a time you're calling `show()`, you've to check the existence in the method itself. [Something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/g8m6Lsuc/).

Comment: This is your code result after applied [Picture](http://i.cubeupload.com/fPnHM6.jpg)

Comment: @LionKing You should ask what you need, this post answers to your question: "I want any way to call init method automatically"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how the data has been initialed and still `null`?
The target of my question is how can I assign initial data to the variables. and when apply your answer, the variables remain has null values.

Comment: When I'm running the code in the fiddle, I get `0` as `slideImagesLen` (or `1` if I uncomment the HTML). The lack of initial values for other properties is just because I don't know them, you've only nulls in your post. That's why I asked you to ask what you actually need.